# What is a good algorithm to detect silence over a variety of recording environments?

Tags: algorithm, audio

My app processes samples from microphone audio streams. **The task I'm asking about:**  programmatically make a good guess at what ranges of the audio stream samples should be considered signal versus noise. The "signal", in this case, is human speech.

The audio I'm getting from users comes from recording environments that I can't control or know much about. These users may be speaking into a professional microphone from a treated space or into a crummy laptop mic in their living room. Very noisy environments with excessive background noise, e.g. a busy restaurant, are outside of what I need to accommodate.

It would make the analysis simpler, but I don't want to request the user to record a room noise sample within my app. And I don't want the user to manually designate a range of audio as silence.

If I'm just looking at recorded audio within a DAW, it is simple and intuitive to spot where silence (nobody talking) is within the waveform. Basically, there's a bunch of relatively flat horizontal lines that are closer to negative infinity db (absolute silence) than any other flat lines.

I have no problems using various sound APIs to access samples. I've omitted technical specifics because I'm just asking about a suitable algorithm, and even if an existing library were available, I'd prefer my own implementation.

What algorithm is good for classifying sample ranges as silence for the requirements I've described?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple algorithm that has its pros and cons:

Perform the calculation of noise floor as described below once. Or to continuously respond to changing conditions during recording, you can perform this calculation at some reasonably responsive interval like once every second.

```
Let K = a constant ratio of noise to signal, e.g. 10%, expected in worst cases.
Let A = the sample with the highest amplitude from the microphone audio stream. 
Noise floor is A * K
```

Once the noise floor has been calculated, you can apply it to any range of the audio stream samples to classify values above the noise floor as signal and below the noise floor as noise.

With the above algorithm, samples are assumed to be stored in a typical computer audio format, e.g. PCM, where 0 is silence and a negative/positive sample value is air pressure creating sound. Negative samples can be negated to positive values when evaluating them.

`K` could be something like 10%. It's the noise/signal ratio expected in one of the poorest recording environments you'd like to support. Analyzing test recordings will show what the ratio should be. The higher the ratio is, the more noise will be miss-classified as signal by the algorithm.

Pros:

- Easy to implement.
- Computationally inexpensive. O(n) for a single pass over a sample array to find the highest peak value.

Cons:

- It depends on the samples used to calculate a noise floor having signal (speech) in them. So there has to be some way of knowing the samples contain signal outside of the algorithm.
- Any loud noises, e.g. a hand clap, that aren't speech but have a higher amplitude, can cause the noise floor to raise above speech causing speech to be miss-classified as noise.
- The K value is a fudge factor. There are more direct ways to detect the actual noise floor from the samples.